# Doubt about $D_1$ and $D_2$ of a function

Tags: analysis, derivatives, manifolds

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by
$$F(x,y) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{($x^2+x^2sin(1/x),y)$} &if\ x \neq 0\\
       \text{$(0,y)$} & if\ x=0 \\
     \end{cases}$$
Show that

i) $D_1F$ exists for every point in $\mathbb{R}^2$

ii)$D_2F$ exists and is continuous in some neighbourhood of $(0,0)$

iii) $F$ is differentiable in $(0,0)$

What I got:
i) if $x \neq 0$ then we have
$\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}(x,y) = 2x(1+sin(1/x))-cos(1/x)$
and $\dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}(x,y)=0.$

if $x=0$ then $\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}(0,y) = 0$ and $\dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}(0,y)=0$.

So $D_1F(x,y) = (2x(1+sin(1/x))-cos(1/x),0)$ if $x \neq 0$ and $D_1F(x,y) = (0,0)$ if $x=0$

ii) How can I show that $D_2F$ exists and is continuous in some neighbourhood of $(0,0)$?

iii) I have no clue about this one.

Any hint would be nice.

---

Edit:
if $x \neq 0$ then
 $\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}(x,y) = 0$ and  $\dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}(x,y) = 1$

if $x=0$ then
 $\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}(0,y) = 0$ and  $\dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}(0,y) = 1$

Therefore $D_2F(x,y) = (0,1)\ \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.Since it is a constant function, we have that is continuous at $(0,0)$(is this right?).

for iii) I know that $DF(0,0) = D_1F(0,0) + D_2F(0,0)$, but
$$\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}(x,y) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{$x^2+x^2sin(1/x)-cos(1/x)$} &if\ x \neq 0\\
       \text{$0$} & if\ x=0 \\
     \end{cases}$$
it's not a continuous function at $x=0$. Can I guarantee that F is differentiable in $(0,0)$ by only $D_2F(x,y)$ be continuous?

Comment: Is there a reason you did not calculate $D_2F$ in a manner analogous to your computation of $D_1F$?  Does that computation give a discontinuity at $x = 0$?

Comment: @EricTowers yes, differentiable, sorry. And no, I got $D_2F(0,y) = (0,1)$. Is that enought?

Comment: To be thorough, you should compute it on both pieces of the piecewise function, then observe that taken together they're actually one constant function on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  This computation and conclusion should be part of your analysis in ii (and should be explicitly added to your question).

Comment: if I do this I guarantee that $DF(0,0) = D_1F(0,0) + D_2F(0,0)$ inputs are continuous functions in a neighborhood of (0,0) and therefore F is differentiable in (0,0)?

Comment: I don't see that your posted work shows that $D_1F$ glues together into a single continuous function.  You really should include your work in your question, otherwise it's impossible to guess where you are stuck.

Comment: I added the details